# Android: OnItemClickListener Wrong View Position

Tags: android, listview, view, position, onitemclicklistener

I have got a Listview with a custom Baseadapter. Also i set an OnItemClickListener wich though is called but it seems that the position of the view isn´t correct.

I want to show a QuickAction at the Position of the clicked item, and it´s not created at the right Position. The Quickaction (mBar) gets the view as a paramter and draws itself at the spezific position. The error MUST be the view´s position / layout params I think.

The listener:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, final long selectedCourseid)
        {
            QuickActionBar mBar = new QuickActionBar(context);
            mBar.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(context, R.drawable.ic_menu_mark, "choose"));
            mBar.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(context, R.drawable.ic_menu_save, "details"));  

            mBar.setOnQuickActionClickListener(new OnQuickActionClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onQuickActionClicked(QuickActionWidget widget, int position)
                {

                          ....

                }
            });

            mBar.show(view);

        }
    });
```

How can I achieve that the position params of the view are correctly set?

The method witch creates the View in the extended Baseadapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder;

        cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();                
            holder.test = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.test);
            ...


    } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        holder.test.setText("test");
             ...


        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above getView() method, just add below line in the else {...} statement:

```
//This will update the position of the holder when the list updated.
holder.position = position
```

I don't know if anyone found the answer yet but somebody might go here and give this a try in case.